# No matching function for call

Tags: c++, stl

```
        static int index = 0;
        class neighbor
        {
            public:
                    int dest ;
                    int weight;
                    neighbor( int d= 0, int w= 0);
        };
        template<typename T>
        class vertexInfo
        {
            public:
                    enum vertexColor { white , grey , black } ;
                    typename  map< T, int>:: iterator vtxMapLoc;
                    set<neighbor> edges;
                     vertexInfo();
                      // default constructor
                     vertexInfo( const map<T, int> :: iterator& iter)
                     {
                        // constructor with iterator pointing to a vertex in map                   
                     }
                     int inDegree;
        };
        template <typename T>
        class graph
        {
            private:

                    typename  map< T, int > :: iterator iter;
                    map <T,int> vtxMap;
                    vector<vertexInfo<T> > vInfo;
                    int numVertices;
                    int numedges;
                    stack<int> availStack;
                    int getvInfoIndex(graph<T>& , const T& v);
            public:
                    void addEdge( graph<T>& , const T&  , const T&  , int );
                    set<T> get_Neighbor( graph<T>& , const T& v) ;
                    void show(graph<T>& );

        };      

template <typename T>
void graph<T> :: addEdge ( graph<T> & g, const T& v1 , const T& v2, int w)
{
    pair <map <char, int> :: iterator, bool> ret ;

     ret = g.vtxMap.insert(pair <char, int >( v1, index));

     if( ret.second)
     {
        index++;
        g.vInfo.push_back(vertexInfo<T>(index));// Error -> 1

      }

     ret = g.vtxMap.insert(pair <char, int >(v2 , index));

     if( ret.second)
     {
        index++;
        g.vInfo.push_back(index)); // Error -> 2
      }
   }
```

I want to push `"index"` value to `vInfo` vector. But getting error.

```
Error 1 - > `No matching function for call to 'vertexInfo<char>:: vertexInfo(Int&)`     
Error 2 ->  `No matching function for call to std :: vector <vertexInfo<char> , std :: allocator <vertexInfo<char> > > push_back(int&)`
```

I tried to push element through both ways but still getting error.
How to remove this error ??

```
UPDATE :
```

By seeing the reply I have updated body of the code. Added two constructor

```
 vertexInfo() //Default constructor

vertexInfo( const map<T, int> :: iterator& iter)
{ 
     // constructor with iterator pointing to a vertex in map i.e. it is initializes the vtxMapLoc data member with the location of the vertex in the map.
}
```

but not understanding how to write constructors body.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

The first error

```
No matching function for call to 'vertexInfo<char>:: vertexInfo(Int&)
```

Means that there's no constructor for type `vertexInfo<char>` which takes `Int` (the type of variable `index` in your code example) as an argument. Simply create such constructor and everything will work.

As for the second error, it's not clear for me, what behavior you want to achieve. You're trying to `push_back` an `int` value into a `vector` of `vertexInfo<char>`. If you want it to create a corresponding `vertexInfo<char>`, you should probably use [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) or `vertexInfo<T>` constructor, as in the first example. And anyway, you will need the constructor defined.

Comment: I have added two constructors but not getting how to write its body. I have tried like   vertexInfo[iter] = vtxMapLoc  but seems wrong.

Comment: @Tushar You stil didn't add any constructors which accept `int` as an only argument.

Comment: @Tushar In constructor you should create your structure (set all its fields) using the data provided. If you don't know how to do that, I don't all the more so.

Comment: I have made constructor vertexInfo( int index){} and its done.  But now facing problem with parameterized constructor.  Basically I am representing graph using map and set. So when I will addEdge( A, B, 2) , addEdge ( B, C, 3) map should store A->0 , B->1 , C->2 ( key -> index) Then this "index will be stored in vector vInfo. Then vInfo[0] will point to some member functions like inDegree(), outDegree(), getNeighbor()  etc.... out of this vtxMapLoc ( which is iterator) should point to map<T,int> again i.e. ( *vInfo[0].vtxMapLoc).first = A  , (*vInfo[1].vtxMapLoc).first = B

Comment: (*vInfo[2].vtxMapLoc).first = C for that I initialized parameterized constructor this way :  vertexInfo( typename  map<T, int> :: iterator& iter): vtxMapLoc{iter} {} but I am getting output as  : segmentation fault , core dumped.  where did I mistake ??

Comment: : for that there is a function getNeighbor() , which return adjacent vertices of desired vertex which I have not included in above code.   Because function is correctly written but problem with parameterized constructor.